# Sharing the XNA executable of my game on dropbox

Tags: xna

I'm currently making a game and I have my artist living in a different city as me.  We share a dropbox folder so that I can see her art, and I thought it should be easy to copy the debug bin folder into the dropbox so that she can see it.  This doesn't work (I can't even run it), so what could I do?

EDIT:

I run the executable in the dropbox folder, and immediately I get the "game.exe" has stopped working.  So obviously I have XNA installed, but my game can't run in this folder.

Comment: did you build it in Release mode, and copy over all the DLLs, as well as the Content folder and any other stuff you need at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify, your artist will need to install the XNA framework as well. Additionally, if your game requires other stuff to be installed (like OpenAL if you use MonoGame), your artist will need that too.

Also, if you're using the XNA content pipeline, this won't work, because the file formats are all in `.xnb` and similar processed formats; you need to use straight-up assets instead.

**Edit:** Beyond that, you will need at *least* the following:

- Release-built .EXE (it's faster than debug)
- XNA and other DLLs that are dumped out in `bin\Release`
- `Content` directory and all subdirectories/files
- Anything else your game needs at runtime (eg. level files or whatever you use)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Select a folder (preferrably empty) where you will publish the contents, and then send it whole to your friend.

Make sure your project is using Reach in its Properties, otherwise it most certainly won't install properly and you'll have to put up with your friend's complaints. :)

[image]

Comment: FYI, this is not enough if you don't have the XNA framework, or any third-party library dependencies that are installed (like OpenAL for  MonoGame)